Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 images show differences in flooded area extent for the same location and date
I am working on flood mapping using Google Earth Engine (GEE) and have observed a difference when comparing Sentinel-1 and Sentinel-2 images for the same location and date.
Sentinel-1 (SAR): Shows more features and details (e.g., roads, buildings, and terrain) that appear to be above water.
Sentinel-2 (Optical): Displays a larger area as inundated compared to Sentinel-1 for the same location.
On visual inspection, Sentinel-2 appears to classify some features as submerged, which Sentinel-1 identifies as non-flooded. I am using Sentinel-1 in VV polarization for analysis and Sentinel-2 true color imagery for water identification.


What could be the possible reasons for this difference between SAR and optical sensors in representing flooded areas?
Below is the code.
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([67.821636, 27.181231]);

var s1img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
                  .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filterDate('2022-08-30', '2022-09-01');

var s1imgVV = s1img.select('VV');
var s1imgVH = s1img.select('VH');
print(s1imgVV.size());
s1imgVV = s1imgVV.mean();
s1imgVH = s1imgVH.mean();

var s2img = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
                  .filterBounds(roi)
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .filterDate('2022-08-30', '2022-09-01');

var s2imgbands = s2img.select('B4', 'B3', 'B2');
print(s2imgbands.size());
s2imgbands = s2imgbands.mean();

Map.centerObject(roi, 13);
Map.addLayer(s2imgbands, {min: 240, max: 2300}, 'Sentinel-2');
Map.addLayer(s1imgVV, {min: -24, max: -1.5}, 'Sentinel-1 VV');
Map.addLayer(s1imgVH, {min: -31, max: -10}, 'Sentinel-1 VH');

